# Подключение домена на apache

Tags: apache, html

Всем привет, вот с какой проблемой столкнулся

Подключил домен на apache, он подключился но вместо этого меня перебрасывает на localhost.

сайт подключил через httpd-vhost.php

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs/web.ru/www"
    ServerName web.ru
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
    <Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs/web.ru/www/">
        Options None
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow, deny
        allow from all
    </Directory><!-- контейнер Directory я приписал позже в надежде что хоть он что-та исправить -->
</VirtualHost>
```

Также я указал в файле hosts.txt

```
127.0.0.1 web.ru
```

Всёравно ничего не вышло

Что мне нужно ещё сделать или заменить?

Comment: Что значит "перебрасывает"? Я не вижу у вас настроек для конкретного домена и в какую папку ему смотреть

Comment: а какие настройки ещё нужны?

Answer (score 1):

В самом начале файла должна присутствовать строка:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Comment: мне это ставить в httpd-vhosts.php, если так то уже установил

Comment: А расширение точно php? 
httpd-vhosts.conf

Listen 80

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>........

Должно работать. Если нет - смотрите что пишет в логах?